# How to replace numeric month with a month's full name

Tags: r, tibble

Change a column with month in number to the actual month name in full using tidyverse package. Please, bear in mind that even though this data has only four months here, my real dataset contains all actual month of the year.

I am new to tidyverse

```
mydata <- tibble(camp = c("Platinum 2018-03","Reboarding 2018","New Acct Auto Jul18", "Loan2019-4"),
              Acct = c(1, 33, 6, 43),
              Balance = c(222, 7744, 949, 123),
              Month = c(1,4,6,8))
```

I expect the output to be 
January, April, June, August etc. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @akrun The question has not been answered, the reason you think it has is because i used the same dataset but with the addition of column of interest. If you can answer my new question, i would appreciate it. the previous answer didn't solve my problem. It returned NA for the data in that column. I'm not sure why but just a hint that the field is saved as a character data type.

Comment: Do you meant it is not a dupe?  I find the same answer here except that it is used in `mutate`

Comment: I reopened it, but it is not clear

Comment: I don't think it's a dupe because when i used either of those codes, it turned the data in that column to NAs. Hence, my problem wasn't solved. when i used 
mutate(MonthName = month.name[Month]). It created the new column but with only NAs as the data.

Comment: @akrun I have solved the problem. So the reason the code didn't work for my real data is because it is a character variable, it also has leading zeros. To solve this i add to remove the leading zeros then convert the data type from character to numeric before running the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

R comes with a `month.name` vector which should be ok as long as you only need English names.

```
mydata %>% mutate(MonthName = month.name[Month])
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  camp                 Acct Balance Month MonthName
  <chr>               <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    
1 Platinum 2018-03        1     222     1 January  
2 Reboarding 2018        33    7744     4 April    
3 New Acct Auto Jul18     6     949     6 June     
4 Loan2019-4             43     123     8 August
```

### Other Languages

If you need other languages use this code (or omit `as.character` to get ordered factor output):

```
library(lubridate)
Sys.setlocale(locale = "French")
mydata %>% mutate(MonthName = as.character(month(Month, label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE)))
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  camp                 Acct Balance Month MonthName
  <chr>               <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    
1 Platinum 2018-03        1     222     1 janvier  
2 Reboarding 2018        33    7744     4 avril    
3 New Acct Auto Jul18     6     949     6 juin     
4 Loan2019-4             43     123     8 août
```

Comment: I tried the first code, it ran but turned the entire data in that field to NAs. That's not what i want.

Comment: @Omomaxi it runs just fine on the data in your question. Perhaps your real data is different - maybe the `Month` column is a factor with more than 12 levels? Or something else?

Comment: @ Gregor  I am not disputing  the fact that it ran, all i am saying is that it turned the entire data in the field to NAs. Also, I checked the levels of the the real data i have and it doesn't have more than 12 levels. these are it's levels when i ran this code.

unique(Southwest$Month)
 [1] "02" "05" "06" "07" "08" "09" "10" "11" "12" "04"

Comment: @G.Grothendeick. I have solved the problem of why your code didn't work initially. So the reason the code didn't work for my real data is because it is a character variable, it also has leading zeros. To solve this i add to remove the leading zeros then convert the data type from character to numeric before running your code. It worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr-lubridate` solution:

```
mydata %>% 
  mutate(Month = lubridate::month(Month, label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE))
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  camp                 Acct Balance Month  
  <chr>               <dbl>   <dbl> <ord>  
1 Platinum 2018-03        1     222 January
2 Reboarding 2018        33    7744 April  
3 New Acct Auto Jul18     6     949 June   
4 Loan2019-4             43     123 August
```