# How to get month name as output from date object?

Tags: r, lubridate

```r
d <- "2021-05-21"
lubridate::month(d)
```

That **gives 5 in output, I want May to be displayed** there.
Any guesses?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your question. Can you provide more information on where the function `month` comes from? You can use the Lubridate package for working with dates or make sure the values have the class `date` (`as.Date`) and use the `format` function. For more information, see the [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) guide.

Comment: Since you're already using `lubridate::month`, the function has an argument `label` to flag whether you want to return the month's number or name

Comment: Several possible duplicates [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57791553/5325862), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50607659/5325862), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22058393/5325862)

Answer (score 8):

We could use `lubridate` package:
The trick here is to set the argument `label` of the function `month`to `TRUE`:

```
library(lubridate)
ymd(d)
month(d, label=TRUE)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `base R`

```
  format(as.Date(d), '%b')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `strftime()`.

```
strftime("2021-05-21", '%b')
# [1] "May"
```

Answer (score 0):

The given example isn't a date object, so you can extract the month from the string

```
month.name[as.numeric(strsplit(d,"-")[[1]][2])]
```

If it is a Date class

```
format(d,"%B")
```